# How to create a custom ManagedScheduledExecutorService in weblogic.xml and use it in java code?

Tags: java, concurrency, weblogic, jndi, scheduledexecutorservice

How can I lookup my custom ManagedScheduledExecutorService that I am defining in the weblogic.xml of my application?

I have tried to use the InitialContext.lookup but it does not work.
It throws the NamingException.

My weblogic.xml looks something like this;

```
    <wl-dispatch-policy>CustomWorkManager</wl-dispatch-policy>
    <work-manager>
        <name>CustomWorkManager</name>
        <min-threads-constraint>
            <name>CustomWorkManager-MinThreads</name>
            <count>1</count>
        </min-threads-constraint>
        <max-threads-constraint>
            <name>CustomWorkManager-MaxThreads</name>
            <count>20</count>
        </max-threads-constraint>
    </work-manager>
    <managed-scheduled-executor-service>
        <name>CustomMSES</name>
        <dispatch-policy>CustomWorkManager</dispatch-policy>
    </managed-scheduled-executor-service>
```

I am trying to lookup my CustomMSES managed scheduled executor service as follows;

```
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
    execService =
            (ManagedScheduledExecutorService) ic.lookup("CustomMSES");
```

Am I missing something?

I am new to the JNDI lookup concept, so I may be doing something wrong.
I do see in blogs that they have added something like "java:comp/env" before the name.
But I could not find a logic for this kind of naming.

I am sure if the JNDI lookup string is rectified I should be able to run my code correctly.

Can anyone help suggest what could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing my lookup value from

```
"CustomMSES"
```

to

```
"java:comp/env/concurrent/CustomMSES"
```

seems to have done the trick!